# Javascript: Changing a boolean in an else if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean

i am having the following problem. I am trying to do this but it is not working:

```
highlight(){

  if (this.firstClick && this.firstMove){
     grid[this.i][this.j+1].toHighlight = true;
     grid[this.i][this.j+2].toHighlight = true;
  } else if (!this.firstClick && this.firstMove) {
     grid[this.i][this.j+1].toHighlight = false;
     grid[this.i][this.j+2].toHighlight = false;
  } else if (this.firtClick && !this.firstMove){
     grid[this.i][this.j+1].toHighlight = true;
     grid[this.i][this.j+2].toHighlight = false;
  } else if (!this.firstClick && !this.firstMove){
     grid[this.i][this.j+1].toHighlight = false;
     grid[this.i][this.j+2].toHighlight = false;
  }

 }
```

As soon as i am changing the boolean the second time in the first else if it said that grid[][].toHighlight is undefined even tho it eveluates to true.

You can look at the full code on my github and how it is working at the moment on the hosted page. I have used it on the black pawn. The white ones have a different logic behind, where i tried something different.

You can find the whole code here:
https://github.com/GreedyCoding

And it is hosted online here:
https://greedycoding.github.io/p5js-Chess

Comment: It's not possible to get such an error message from the provided code. Please add the real error message to the post. Also, take care of spelling of your variable names, `this.firtClick !== this.firstClick`.

Comment: I forgot to push it to GitHub. It should throw out the error now.

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") __must include__ the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and __the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself__. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._"

Comment: like i said in the comment 7 minutes before yours, the code is throwing out the error at the moment. i just forgot to push it to github. The whole code is there too on github.

Comment: The comment above is a direct cite from a close reason. "__Must include ... the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.__". The question becomes totally useless for the future visitors when you fix the code on Github. That's why we need the reproducible code included in the post itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the second else if statement

```
else if (this.firtClick && !this.firstMove){
```

it should be **firstClick** not sure if this is the reason but hope it helps.

Comment: Already edited it and pushed it to github. Same error as before. Thanks for the help.

Comment: my bad didn't see the previous comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Examining your if / else if blocks - it is apparent that the there is some cleaning up that can be done

Essentially dividing the two basic divisions - based on if firstClick or not and then within each of those - determining if it is the first move or not
There are common values that can be applied in each condition - not the use of the ternary equation in the first if block (and its not needed in the second one at all.

```
highlight(){
  if (this.firstClick){
     grid[this.i][this.j+1].toHighlight = true;

     this.firstMove
        ? grid[this.i][this.j+2].toHighlight = true
        : grid[this.i][this.j+2].toHighlight = false;
  } else {
     grid[this.i][this.j+1].toHighlight = false;
     grid[this.i][this.j+2].toHighlight = false;
  } 
 }
```

Comment: Even what you have can be DRY more. Just change boolean in ternary ...`grid[this.i][this.j+2].toHighlight = this.firstMove ? true:false`

Comment: Thank you at first. I tried this and it seems to go throught the if loop without problems and it throws the error at this line when it tries to change back the boolean to false in the else loop. Seems like its the same as with my if else loop.                                      } else {
      grid[this.i][this.j+1].toHighlight = false;

Comment: Are you sure its not just a scope issue - you are referencing "this" - but its not set in the highlight function (and therefore would miss the if loop and go into the else block and then fail since there is not "this" object to reference.

Comment: If i only run the if loop without an else statement it will highlight the cells normally. So it should not be a scope issue since it can set it in the if loop right? Correct me if i am wrong. But i can set the boolean of grid[i1][i2].toHighlight to true in the if loop. I just cant set it back to false in the else if statement.

Comment: but where are you setting "i" and "j" in this function - of course it will work if you hard code the variables but you are incrementing the "i" by 1 and the "j" by 2 - where are those variable set?

Comment: the cells have a i and a j thats there position on the grid. i am taking these values to determine the cells to highlight. i are the colums j are the rows The whole code is there on github for you to look at it.